# Can I use the svmono Springer template files for self publishing a book outside of Springer?

Tags: books, book-design, sv-classes, publishing

I want to self publish a Math book and would like to use the svmono style template files as the base. I checked the files themselves, the Springer publishing guide, but nowhere do they reference the specifics of how the template files are licensed, if they are copyright free or if they require permissions / attribution. Does anyone know if this is permitted or can point me to a link? The book would be released at cost, if this makes a difference.

https://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics?SGWID=0-40292-2-122598-0

Comment: This is a legal question and so not clearly on topic, it would look as if you can but if in doubt ask Springer.

Comment: Thanks David! I did email to ask, no response yet.

Comment: You probably won't get one. But keep a record of the fact that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs to know. I heard back from Springer, and they have confirmed that the svmono style files are free of copyright.

Comment: Even if a publisher claims copyright, it's not necessarily an indication that a document class can't be used for one's own purposes, including self-publication.  The AMS classes are copyrighted, but there are no restrictions on their use.  (Just don't claim that you created them.)